# Does Hibernate 4.3-final causing GooGooStatementCache Multiply prepared statement?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data, c3p0

we have a spring project where we use

`Spring` + `Spring Data` + `Hibernate` + `c3p0`

Everything worked fine till few last versions. We started to see **a lot** of 
`INFO GooGooStatementCache:441` in our log. Moreover, after some memory issues in our server side. We started to do some analyzing of our java memory heap. seems like that in all the versions that we get a lot of `INFO GooGooStatementCache:441` we have serious memory leak. `com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection`  does NOT get free. because of that we have many connection s that left opened.

Our suspect that the change from `hibernate 3.6.3.Final`(`hibernate-entitymanager`) to `hibernate 3.0.Final` is causing those problems.

Anyone else experience something like that ?

Thanks,

Alon

**EDIT:**
Switching between:

```
    <!-- <jpa.version>2.0.0</jpa.version> -->
    <hibernate.version>4.3.0-Final</hibernate.version>
    <hibernate.entitymanager.version>4.3.0.Final</hibernate.entitymanager.version>

    <!-- <hibernate.jpa-api.version>2.0-cr-1</hibernate.jpa-api.version> -->
```

To:

```
    <jpa.version>2.0.0</jpa.version>
    <hibernate.version>3.5.6-Final</hibernate.version>
```

And this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.java-persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>jpa-api</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.jpa-api.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.entitymanager.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

To:

```
    <!-- Hibernate and JPA -->
    <!-- seems like we get jppa api from hibernate-entitymanager -->
    <!-- <dependency> -->
    <!-- <groupId>org.hibernate.java-persistence</groupId> -->
    <!-- <artifactId>jpa-api</artifactId> -->
    <!-- <version>${hibernate.jpa-api.version}</version> -->
    <!-- <scope>compile</scope> -->
    <!-- </dependency> -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.entitymanager.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

prevents the `INFO GooGooStatementCache:441 - Multiply prepared statement!` issue 
so seems there is some kind of problem with our settings and hibernate 4.3.0-final

any ideas?

**EDIT 2**:

<strike>changing to 4.3.1.Final does **NOT** solves this issue</strike>

**EDIT 3**
thanks for the response
my guess is that its something that doesnt work right with the `c3p0` and  the new `hibernate`

here is how we set them

```
<!-- Declare a datasource that has pooling capabilities-->   
<bean id="jpaDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
    destroy-method="close"
    p:driverClass="${app.jdbc.driverClassName}"
    p:jdbcUrl="${app.jdbc.url}"
    p:user="${app.jdbc.username}"
    p:password="${app.jdbc.password}"
    p:acquireIncrement="5"
    p:idleConnectionTestPeriod="60"
    p:maxPoolSize="100"
    p:maxStatements="50"
    p:minPoolSize="10" />

<!-- Declare a JPA entityManagerFactory -->
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" 
    p:persistenceXmlLocation="classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml"
    p:persistenceUnitName="hibernatePersistenceUnit"
    p:dataSource-ref="jpaDataSource"
    p:jpaVendorAdapter-ref="hibernateVendor"/>

<!-- Specify our ORM vendor -->
<bean id="hibernateVendor" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
            p:showSql="false"/>

<!-- Declare a transaction manager-->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" 
    p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
```

and here is persistence file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    version="1.0">
<persistence-unit name="hibernatePersistenceUnit"
    transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value=${show.sql} /> 
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect"    value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
    </properties>
    <mapping-file>META-INF/orm.xml</mapping-file>
</persistence-unit>
 </persistence>
```

**EDIT 4**
seems that move to hibernate 4.3.1.FINAL **DOES** fixes the issue. dont get any warning about prepare statement to log. and memory analyzer doesnt show any leak on db connection.

**question**
what is the best way to connect `hibernate` and `c3p0` and `spring`? using `hibernate-c3p0` package  or adding `c3p0` package to pom?

Answer (score 6):

So, I can't explain why you are seeing more of this in newer versions of Hibernate, but what the message you are seeing means is that your application is trying to prepare a PreparedStatement that has already been prepared and cached by the very same database Connection. However, the cached Statement cannot be used, because it is still in use, it has not yet been close()ed. So a new copy of the same Statement is being prepared. (The cache will hold both copies, in case you simultaneously reuse the Statement often.)

In theory, there are scenarios in which this might be exactly what you intend to do. For example, while traversing recursive structures flattened into a database table, you might reuse the same query with different parameters to drill down levels while a top level query remains open.

Still, in practice this is rare. Usually if you are getting this message, it probably means that your application is not promptly close()ing Statements. From what you describe, it sounds like you might have a Connection leak too, though you haven't reported the usual result of that, the app hangs when the pool reaches `maxPoolSize`. (You haven't reported much about your c3p0 config; maybe you have set `maxPoolSize` very large and you run into memory problems before pool exhaustion.)

Some things you might try:

1) Check if you have a Connection leak. See [here](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_to_debug_and_workaround_broken_clients)

2) Simplify the issue: See if the problem is limited to Statement caching by turning Statement caching off and comparing behavior. Set c3p0 params `maxStatements` and `maxStatementsPerConnection` both to zero.

Comment: hey, thanks for response. i have edited my question and added the way it set c3p0. The thing about the "PreparedStatement " warning is that i see it alot. and according the heap memory analyzing the memory doesn't succeed to get free.

Comment: it does sound like you are leaking Connections (when Connections are close()ed, c3p0 closes/checks-in their subsidiary Statements too), except it remains a mystery why you don't run out of 100 Connections fairly quickly. If you get a chance, please do try setting `unreturnedConnectionTimeout` and `debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces` (see the link in my response for details) and see whether Connections are failing to get checked in. (is your app careful about close()ing hibernate Sessions reliably in finally blocks, isolated from any previous Exceptions that might occur in finally?)

Comment: thanks @Steve. i'll check it out. but i still dont get it why we don't get this kind of behavior with hibernate 3 and we do get it with hibernate 3. maybe some mismatch configuration of hibernate 4 and c3p0?

Comment: question: why not to set up 'unreturnedConnectionTimeout' always? what is the default value?

Comment: there shouldn't be... c3p0 at least tries very, very hard to conserve behavior (i tend to add config params for new behavior but leave old behaviors as default, unless the old is unequivocably bad). do upgrade to a recent c3p0, at least 0.9.2.1 (current "production") or better yet 0.9.5-pre6 (a bit rougher, but solid at its core). lots of hibernate 4 apps use c3p0 without issue. i hope you do get a chance to check for Connection leaks, and to see whether the issue survives if you disable statement caching.

Comment: you can set up `unreturnedConnectionTimeout` in production. i recommend against it on the theory that it's better to find and eliminate Connection leaks than to have c3p0 clean up after bugginess in your app, but sometimes application code can't be messed with and `unreturnedConnectionTimeout` is a fine workaround. don't leave `debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces` set in production. it will slow down every Connection checkout.